# ASP.NET Boilerplate Auth from Windows Phone 8.1 - bearer token

Tags: asp.net, authentication, windows-phone-8, asp.net-web-api, boilerplate

I'm using asp.net boilerplate for my website. There I have standard authentication from aspnetboilerplate/module-zero(OWIN).

But now I need athentication for my windows phone app(wp8.1)
I was trying configure my application for authorization with bearer but I failed..
How configurate asp.net boilerplate application for my windows phone app auth?

In windows phone app I send post to my web api like this:

```
public static async Task<TokenResponseModel> GetBearerToken(string siteUrl, string Username, string Password)
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(siteUrl);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();

            HttpContent requestContent = new StringContent("grant_type=password&username=" + Username + "&password=" + Password, Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

            HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = await client.PostAsync("Token", requestContent);

            if (responseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                string jsonMessage;
                using (Stream responseStream = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
                {
                    jsonMessage = new StreamReader(responseStream).ReadToEnd();
                }

                TokenResponseModel tokenResponse = (TokenResponseModel)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonMessage, typeof(TokenResponseModel));

                return tokenResponse;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
```

But what should I do in WebApi? How auth and next response bearer and how auth in next step using bearer when on class i have [AbpAuthorize]?

Comment: may be it will help you 
[ASP.NET Identity and mobile clients]


  : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22126305/asp-net-identity-and-mobile-clients

Answer (score 0):

This now documented and implemented in module zero template

code:
In module WebApi:

```
Configuration.Modules.AbpWebApi().HttpConfiguration.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter("Bearer"));
```

In controller WebApi:

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<AjaxResponse> Authenticate(LoginModel loginModel)
    {
        CheckModelState();

        var loginResult = await GetLoginResultAsync(
            loginModel.UsernameOrEmailAddress,
            loginModel.Password,
            loginModel.TenancyName
            );

        var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(loginResult.Identity, new AuthenticationProperties());

        var currentUtc = new SystemClock().UtcNow;
        ticket.Properties.IssuedUtc = currentUtc;
        ticket.Properties.ExpiresUtc = currentUtc.Add(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30));

        return new AjaxResponse(OAuthBearerOptions.AccessTokenFormat.Protect(ticket));
    }
```

documentation: http://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Zero/Startup-Template#token-based-authentication